how to make all elements of side panel the same width in flexbox?
I've been trying to center the left and right panel below the header so that header and those panels are in one line (text from the header is exacly below the text from the lower section from both sides).But I can't make the items from the left of my side panel to wrap (the long paragraph).


import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #1F2937;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #F9FAF8;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.links {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #E5E7EB;
  display: flex;
  gap: 18px;
}

.hero {
  background-color: #1F2937;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
}

.hero-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.hero-right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start
}

.hero-title {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #F9FAF8;
}

.hero-text {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #E5E7EB;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.sign-up {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3882F6;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: none;
}

.image-placeholder {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 200px;
  width: 450px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a:hover,
a:visited,
a:link,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
<header>
  <div class="logo">Header Logo</div>
  <ul class="links">
    <li><a href="#">header link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">header link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">header link</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
<div class="hero">
  <div class="hero-left">
    <p class="hero-title">This website is awesome</p>
    <p class="hero-text">This website has some subtext that goes under the main title.It's smaller font and the color is lower contrast
    </p>
    <button class="sign-up">Sign up</button>
  </div>
  <div class="hero-right">
    <div class="image-placeholder">
      <p>this is placeholder for an image</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



I've been trying to use max width property for the left side but it won't give me the exact outcome and it's probably not a good way to solve this

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

To fix your current problem, you should remove the flex-wrap property from your .hero selector. The flex-wrap property controls the wrapping behavior of flex items within the flexbox. By having flex-wrap: wrap; on your .hero selector, you are allowing the items to wrap, which isn't what you want. You can find more about flex-wrap here.
This is what your .hero block should look like.
.hero {
  background-color: #1F2937;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* Removed flex-wrap */
  gap: 20px;
}

This should fix your primary problem. However, since the content on your site is not currently responsive, you might face issues with elements being cut off or not displayed fully. To solve these issues, avoid setting your widths, heights, font sizes, etc. in pixels. Instead, try to use relative units like rem, em, or % so everything is relative to the size of the view window.
For example:
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px; /* Now, 1rem = 16px */
}

.hero-title {
  font-size: 3rem; /* 3rem = 48px */
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #F9FAF8;
}

